# Multiple data-target in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap you can toggle a `.collapse` element using button as I have done in my code.
I am new to Bootstrap and understand that we are using `data-toggle` to select the property and `data-target` to select the element. But is there any way/syntax/options for multiple element and properties to be selected sth like `data-target="#demo + #demo1 + #demo2"`?

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
    <div id="demo" class="collapse in">Demo</div>
    <div id="demo1" class="collapse in">Demo1</div>
    <div id="demo2" class="collapse in">Demo2</div>
```